# Syntax errors when copying variables from Bootstrap to custom.scss

Tags: css, sass

I am following a course on using Bootstrap and SASS. I have a style.scss file that has @use'custom'; and a _custom.scss file to set custom themes using Bootstrap. I have followed every step exactly, we are at a part where I am copying variables from the _variables.scss file and when I copy them from variables to custom, I get what seem like syntax errors which doesn't seem right at all. I have everything set up exactly as the instructor does, yet he isn't receiving any errors like I am. Am I missing something?

In the terminal it says:

Error: expected ";".
╷
6 │ $white:    #fff;
│       ^
╵
scss_custom.scss 6:7  @use
scss\style.scss 1:1    root stylesheet

Below is the code inside _custom.scss :

```css
//Import BOOTSTRAP V5
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"

$white:    #fff;
$gray-100: #f8f9fa;
$gray-200: #e9ecef;
$gray-300: #dee2e6;
$gray-400: #ced4da;
$gray-500: #adb5bd;
$gray-600: #6c757d;
$gray-700: #495057;
$gray-800: #343a40;
$gray-900: #212529;
$black:    #000;
```

Comment: You are missing the semi-colon after you import bootstrap -- the error clearly tells you this `Error: expected ";".`

Comment: Obviously it's not clear enough. It says it's expected after "white".

Comment: It's reporting where the parser ran into an issue, error reporting can only point you in the right direction. It will take time to become a bit more familiar with tracking down the source of bugs but it'll become second nature eventually